# Correct tense for sentence

Tags: conditional-constructions, future-tense, future-perfect

For example in this sentence:

If the club *limited* its membership, it *will have to* raise its dues.

In this, first part of sentence is conditional and is a probable event for future. But I am not sure which future tense it will be in. Similarly second part is depends on first part and will be completed at some point in future. So it seems that it is correct to use *will have to*(Future Perfect).

Comment: *will have to* here is not Future Perfect but simple Future: *have* is not an auxiliary but the infinitive of the lexical verb *have* in the phrasal *have to* = *must*.

Comment: Are there some rules to decide when it is simple future + infinitive or future perfect?

Comment: It's almost never necessary to use a future perfect in a conditional. What *looks* like a future perfect in my answer, *would have had to raise its dues* is not a future perfect but the same construction used as a modal past. See [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7537/32) answer.

Answer (score 5):

*If the club limited its membership, it will have to raise its dues* is not ordinarily a grammatical construction. For it to be grammatical you would have to be speaking of an uncertain but possible past condition with a necessary future consequence:

> I don't know whether the club limited its membership last year; but if it limited its membership then it is certain that it will have to raise its dues in the future.

It is more likely that you are speaking of a present possibility—will the club limit its membership or not? And what will be the consequence if it does? If you think it **is** possible, then you are dealing with a *realis* (real) situation: you will use the simple present form of *limit* in the condition (*IF*) clause and a simple future form of *will* in the consequence (*THEN*) clause.

**REALIS NON-PAST**

> The club is now saying that if it **limits** its membership it **will** have to raise its dues.**

If you think it is not possible that it is not possible that the club will limit its membership you are dealing with an *irrealis* (unreal) situation: you will use the past form of *limit* in the condition clause and the past form of *will* in the consequence clause. The past forms here mark serve as markers of irreality:

**IRREALIS NON-PAST**

> The club will not limit its membership now because if it **limited** its membership it **would** have to raise its dues.

If, however, you are speaking of a *realis* **past** possibility—something the club was thinking about last year, for instance—you also use the past forms of *limit* and *will*. Here the past forms mark past tense rather than irreality.

**REALIS PAST**

> The club said last year that if it **limited** its membership it **would** have to raise its dues.

And if you are speaking of an *irrealis* past situation—one you know did **not** come to pass—you use what looks like a perfect construction to mark this as past irrealis:

**IRREALIS PAST**

> The club did not limit its membership last year because if it **had limited** its membership it **would have had** to raise its dues.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam They are correct as they stand in my Answer.

Comment: I am still not clear how to decide which among `will/would` has to be used. Could you elaborate more on why you chose would in second sentence. Also what do you mean by "is not a grammatical construction". Sorry for being naive, I am just in initial stages of leaning

Comment: "Is not a grammatical construction" = "is wrong".  :-)